# Querying different levels in your database laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Good day. Am trying to query my database to get the child of a child of a child. Every user has 2 children. Am using query builder. The requirements is not to use eloquent and eloquent relationships. But am struggling with it.

```
DB::table('users') - >where('parent_id',  Auth::user() ->id) - get() ;
```

If I want to get the children of those children the query results gave, how will I do so?

Comment: Can please share the db Schema for parent, child and child relationship ?

Comment: every user including parent and child has a parent_id and a parented _by column. Every other thing is basic

Answer (score 1):

I have considered your scenario like this -

DB schema -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `parent_id`, `parent_by`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),(2, 1, 3), (3, 2, 4), (4, 2, 5),(5, 3, 6),(6, 3, 7),
(7, 4, 8), (8, 4, 9)(9, 5, 10), (10, 5, 11);
```

And the raw query to get grandparent, parent, child and child's child -

```
SELECT a.`parent_id` AS grandparent, a.`parent_by` AS parent, b.`parent_by` AS child, c.`parent_by` AS child_child
FROM  `user` AS a
LEFT JOIN  `user` AS b ON b.`parent_id` = a.`parent_by` 
LEFT JOIN  `user` AS c ON c.`parent_id` = b.`parent_by` 
WHERE a.`parent_id` =1
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks though a user with an ID 1 might not necessarily be parented by someone with ID 2 or so. A parent with ID 2 might have children with ID 20 or so

Comment: Your welcome, And yes i know.. This query will work on that condition as well .this schema and values is just for the understanding of the scenario for the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

With join it'll be complected,Use loop :

```
$Childs= DB::table('users')->where('parent_id',  Auth::user()->id)->get() ;
foreach ($users as $usr){
    $users['sub_childs'] = DB::table('users')->where('parent_id',  $usr->id)->get() ;
}
```

For recursive relationships use this: https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: This loop will not get the child of a child down to three or four generations. It looks simpler and less code though. Thanks though I would be grateful if you could show me something to get the child of a child

Comment: Then you need to recursive relationships model